# Is there a way to enable Okta Single Sign-On functionality in an Angular-based Excel add-in?

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, okta, excel-addins

I have an Angular Excel add-in that I would like to integrate Okta Single Sign-On (SSO) functionality into so that users can log in through the add-in. I've looked for relevant documentation but haven't been able to find any.

Could you please provide assistance or guidance on how to integrate Okta SSO with the Excel add-in?

I'm hoping for something similar, but implemented or integrated with Okta.
[Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)